# Managed package: corrupted permission sets?

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, isv, package, package-install

Our managed package is failing to install in target orgs (DE, EE).  The error that is thrown during installation is "Unable to Access Page", with a reference to one of the permission sets in the package.  The rest of the message is "The value of the "{0}" parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information."

I wrote about this issue before and thought I had solved it: [Package install worked yesterday, but not today. Very strange error reported](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46434/package-install-worked-yesterday-but-not-today-very-strange-error-reported/49240#49240)

Sadly, it has come back.  What I noticed, however, is that the metadata for the permission sets has some extra "stuff" in it (tabSettings to be specific), relative to a freshly-created permission set.  So I figured I would just manually remove the XML and re-compile the metadata back to the org.  I can save the metadata to the org just fine (no errors)...but the extra XML is not removed.

I think the extra XML constitutes "corrupted" permission sets and of course I want to just replace them with new ones, but I can't remove them from the managed-released package!

Has anybody seen something similar?  Any advice for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Winter 15 is giving nightmares to a lot of people, we are facing out own set of issues with it, so considering the urgency you might want to get "Delete components from managed package" enabled for your dev org for the time being to remove the permission set.
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=viewing_deleted_components.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Don't use winter'15. Until it is on production

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, this problem is happening with *both* Summer '14 and Winter '15 pre-release orgs.  EE, sandbox and DE.

Comment: Also, I did ask for the "delete components from managed package" option enabled...but permission sets can't be deleted!  That's frustrating for sure.

Comment: Nasty - did you sort this out?